# INotifyPropertyChanged does not work

Tags: c#, xaml, geolocation, windows-phone-8.1

Probably not the best solution, but I noticed that a lot of different pages and user controls of my app use the same data (mostly by binding), so I made the following class

```
public class GPSHelper : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private double _speed;
        public double Speed
        {
            get
            {
                return _speed;
            }
            set
            {
                _speed = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Speed");
            }
        }
        public double AvgSpeed { get; set; }
        public double MaxSpeed { get; set; }
        public double Distance { get; set; }
        public double Altitude { get; set; }
        public double Longtitude { get; set; }
        public double Latitude {get; set;}
        private int _locationChangedCounter;
        private Geolocator _locator; 
        public GPSHelper()
        {
            _locator = new Geolocator();
            _locator.MovementThreshold = 0.5;
            _locator.PositionChanged += locator_PositionChanged;
            MaxSpeed = 0;
            AvgSpeed = 0;
            Speed = 30; 
        }

        private async void locator_PositionChanged(Geolocator sender, PositionChangedEventArgs args)
        {

            Geoposition position = await _locator.GetGeopositionAsync();
            Geopoint point = args.Position.Coordinate.Point;
            //Speed = position.Coordinate.Speed.Value;
            Speed = 120; 
            Altitude = point.Position.Altitude;
            if(Speed > MaxSpeed)
            {
                MaxSpeed = Speed; 
            }
            AvgSpeed += Speed / _locationChangedCounter;
            _locationChangedCounter++;
        }

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyname)
        {
            if(PropertyChanged!=null)
            {
                 PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

And in App.xaml I added the class as a resource, I did not know whether I could do that but it still seems like quite a good idea.

```
<Application
    x:Class="SpeedometerGPS.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:SpeedometerGPS"
    xmlns:helpers ="using:SpeedometerGPS.Helpers">
    <Application.Resources>
        <helpers:GPSHelper x:Key="GPSHelper" /> 
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

The only problem I have now is that PropertyChanged won't work and it is giving a quite valid reason why - ,,The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread."  Any suggestions how to work around it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem my self, having the Geolocator as a static member in App.xaml.cs and actually using it at first in OnLaunch() and then assigning the event handler   solved the problem for a while but the whole program crashed after a minute or so. After googling for hours it turned out that in order to use the dispatcher in the class the way I wanted you have to do something like this. However thank you all for your effort, whether you are reading or not.

```
await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority,() => {})
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the event that is coming in, is not on the GUI thread but on a worker thread. 
You are then manipulating the speed, which I assume is part of some binding.
If it is part of some binding, updating the speed is going to have effect in those bindings but this only works if the change happens in the GUI.

Bottom line, you have to dispatch the change of the speed, or the whole event to the GUI thread.

Dispatching to the GUI thread is explained here :
[The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread in window 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218911/the-application-called-an-interface-that-was-marshalled-for-a-different-thread-i)

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    Speed = 120; 
});
```

Comment: Is that a windows phone thing not dispatching for bindings? I know for WPF it automatically dispatches, but I also know that many things in WPF xaml do not work on windows phone xaml.

Comment: I am aware about the dispatcher ,  but where am I suppose to dispatch the speed change if  it is not possible to use it in the code I posted above ?

Comment: In WPF most events are already on the GUI thread, hence there is no need for dispatching but in windows phone most events are not on the GUI thread.

Comment: DDavid, did you follow the link. It shows howto dispatch.

Comment: @DDavid you would likely make the dispatcher call in `private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyname)` and would have `PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));` called on the UI thread.

Comment: I can't use the dispatcher in that class at all, it is not aware about the dispatchers existence, it is a simple class that does not have anything to do with the UI on its own. At least that's how I understand it.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck What deployment ? Does not exist , like at all. I have  Windows.Phone.Management.Deployment but it's something completely else(

Comment: DDavid then you need to post more code, there must be somebody that creates the GPShelper class in the first place, maybe that class can do the dispatching. I don't have your code here so I can't tell.

Comment: Yeah, okay, I mentioned in the post that it's a resource in App.xaml but I will add it as code, not a problem.

Comment: OK it is a resource and where is the resource used ? I think it is not such a good idea to have this in the resources. Why don't you make it an attribute of some other class ? And why not pass that class to the constructor of the helper ?

Comment: It's used as a data context for various pages and controls. For example I have an arrow who's movement animation is bound to the Speed property, I have a textblock that shows the speed and is bound to the same property. I don't use it in code behind anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

The Geolocator documentation says :

"Important  Call the RequestAccessAsync before accessing the user’s location. At that time, your app must be in the foreground and RequestAccessAsync must be called from the UI thread. Until the user grants your app permission to their location, your app can't access location data."

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.geolocator

So you should have your Geolocator as static property somewhere else (like App.xaml.cs for exemple) and call RequestAccessAsync from a method in the UI thread before getting any event.

Comment: The Geolocator works fine, the error shows up in the NotifyPropertyChanged method.

Comment: Yes but the change of speed occurs in the method locator_PositionChanged which is obviously called from another thread than the UI thread (seeing your error "The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread"). And this method is called by the PositionChangedEvent.